# Creating a chat module along with location tracker

Tags: android, chat

I am working on a project that tracks location of the users and also has the feature to chat with one another. I have completed the location tracking which has uses a external database (000webhost) and has the following sub modules:

1. Login and Registration
2. Friend Request
3. Adding a Friend
4. Deleting a friend
5. Viewing the locations of a selected friend on the google map.

My doubt is how should i work on the chat module, that gives an additional option to chat along with viewing locations. I do not want to check if the fellow user is online or not. It should just be able to send and receive messages when the user logs in to the app.
I hope my question is clear now.

Comment: what should your chat be able to do? there are many possibilities. An start would be looking at the Java Message Service and its distributions. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service  Or do you want to write the messenger and it's server on your own and completly in java with an android client?

Comment: This question is off topic, it is asking for opinions on what library/program/framework to use.

Comment: Zerp is right. This forum is intented for asking specific programming questions and not opinion based stuff. But as many people come to your question I would rather give them a point where to start, than just closing the questions as off-topic. As a hint to you Zareen try to edit and rewrite the question and show us, what you have already been looking at during your research and ask a more specific question.

Comment: @Zerp I am sorry for asking an off topic question. I did not know where to clear my doubt  so I thought of posting it here. 
I have edited my question, please do have a look.

Answer (score 0):

An start would be looking at the [Java Message Service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service) and its distributions.  Or do you want to write the messenger and it's server on your own and completly in java with an android client?

But at first you should think of, what does your chat application need to do. Reading your description remembers me of the facebook messenger.